# php if elseif then what?

Tags: php

This is my PHP code

The problem points I have mentioned in comments inside the code portion

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['rdoption1']))
    {
        $var1 = $_POST["rdoption1"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rdoption2']))
    {
        $var2 = $_POST["rdoption2"];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['rdoption1']))
    {
        $message = "Please select Option1";
    }
    elseif(!isset($_POST['rdoption2']))
    {
        $message = "Please select Option2";
    }
    elseif($_POST['rdoption2'] == "checkSetXY")
    {
        if($_POST["valXLocation"] == "")
        {
            $message = "You forget to enter X value.";
        }
        elseif($_POST["valYLocation"] == "")
        {
            $message = "You forget to enter Y value.";
        }
    } // till here all is good. I get all error messages if anything is left vacant or not clicked on radio button
    elseif(empty($_POST['txtoption3'])) //this is not working //the issue is if i select rdoption1  any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further..
    {
        $message = "Please enter your name.";
    }
                else
    {               
        //insert into db
                 }
       }
```

This is html form with PHP echos
Here I'm getting messages where they shall be but not when I select `checkSetXY` value

```
        <?php if(!empty($message)){ echo $message; } ?>

        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form1.php">

          Space portion:
              <input type="radio" name="rdoption1" value="RJ"/>space 1
              <input type="radio" name="rdoption1" value="SM" />space 2


            Pixel Location
                <div class="formText">
                <input type="radio" name="rdoption2" value="checkSetXY"/> Specify Location
                    X: <input type="text" id="locField" name="valXLocation">  
                    Y: <input type="text" id="locField" name="valYLocation"> 
                <input type="radio" name="rdoption2" value="checkDefault"/>Default

                <input type="text" class="input" name="txtoption3">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
           </form>
```

Now I'm confused why is it not taking `elseif` of `txtoption3`

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to make a diagram on this IF/IF ELSE/ELSE sequence, because it can be a little dizzy!

Comment: the issue is if i select rdoption1  any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work because, it will be always set. So, use `empty();`

```
elseif(empty($_POST['txtoption3'])) //this is not working
```

**Explanation**

You are posting a form `input`. When you send it without filling anything, it just sends this value. `""`

An empty string is **not equal** to `null` or **not set**.

Also, as [Peter Szymkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994054/peter-szymkowski) said, check out the [fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/k4jEjT).

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Added your reference. :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski the issue is if i select rdoption1  any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further..

Comment: @user2057047 why not removing `elseif` and `if(empty($message)){ /* add to db */ }else{ echo $message }`. Basically `$message` will act as an error flag

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski what you suggest i m not able to get.. can u elaborate it further plz?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski i agreee.. but it does not answer my question.. :( the problem is still opene ;(

Comment: @user2057047 Did you replace with `empty()` or not?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i replaced it.. and it solved the problem.. it is showing empty box error.. but the problem is diffrent.. 
This is the issue

Comment: @user2057047 [what is the issue, everything works fine??](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rUQoxB)

Comment: @PraveenKumar the issue is if i select rdoption1 any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski the issue is if i select rdoption1 any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further

Comment: @user2057047 Do you have a website where you can give a live demo? No fiddles, as they won't handle `POST` or `GET` effectively.

Comment: what is "next code logic", i don't see any more code logic in your question, and fiddle works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Textfields are set if they are empty. You have to check with `empty($_POST['txtoption3'])` .

Comment: the issue is if i select rdoption1  any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further..

Comment: Text fields can also contain real data (the number 0) when `empty` still returns true.

Answer (score -1):

that is the else for 
if($_POST['rdoption2'] == "checkSetXY")

which I guess is true so it will not go into that else

Comment: the issue is if i select rdoption1  any option and rdoption2 checkDefault next code logic work.. but next code logic does not work when i click on the radio of checkSetXY and enter x and y values.. It simply does not execute code further..